# Chain stalls because of inherent transaction

Tags: hook, inherent

I have a question about `on_finalize` hook and inherent transactions. I have added an inherent transaction to [starknet pallet](https://github.com/keep-starknet-strange/madara/blob/main/crates/pallets/starknet/src/lib.rs#L409) in the Madara repo, that fetches the sequencer address from the local offchain storage of a node authoring the block, and puts it into the pallet storage. There is a boolean storage item `SeqAddrUpdate` that keeps track of whether there has been an update of the sequencer address in each block.

Inherent:

```
#[pallet::call_index(0)]
#[pallet::weight((0, DispatchClass::Mandatory))]
pub fn set_sequencer_address(origin: OriginFor<T>, addr: [u8; 32]) -> DispatchResult {
    ensure_none(origin)?;
    assert!(!SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::exists(), "Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block");
    SequencerAddress::<T>::put(addr);
    SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::put(true);
    Ok(())
}
```

Hook:

```
fn on_finalize(_n: T::BlockNumber) {
    assert!(SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::take(), "Sequencer address must be set for the block");

    ...
}
```

Expected behaviour: for block N, the inherent checks that `SeqAddrUpdate` is `false`, updates the `SequencerAddress`, and sets `SeqAddrUpdate` to `true`. Another attempt to update the storage item results in a panic. Then the `on_finalize` hook checks that the value is `true`, and does `.take()` on the value, so the storage item is again `false`.

In the `build` function for `GenesisConfig` we initialize the value like so:

```
SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::put(self.seq_addr_updated);
```

1. If the value is set to `true`, the inherent panics during block 1, but after the panic message, the chain keeps producing blocks. It makes sense, because the inherent expects to see `false`. Trace:

```
Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block', /Users/lana/github/madara/crates/pallets/starknet/src/lib.rs:415

This is a bug. Please report it at:

    support.anonymous.an

2023-06-22 21:30:12 Evicting failed runtime instance error=Runtime panicked: Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block
2023-06-22 21:30:12 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-06-22 21:30:12 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-06-22 21:30:12 ❗️ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block. Dropping.    
2023-06-22 21:30:12  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (0 ms) [hash: 0x72f03e4de7c72b5d3faa03375e148fd9fbd491ca2d7335e3ebe3c7f1d256d208; parent_hash: 0x4bd0…0321; extrinsics (1)
```

2. But, if at genesis the value is set to `false`, the chain stalls completely, and we see both panics, even though they are supposed to exclude each other:

```
Thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Sequencer address must be set for the block', /Users/lana/github/madara/crates/pallets/starknet/src/lib.rs:167

This is a bug. Please report it at:

    support.anonymous.an

2023-06-22 21:58:48 Evicting failed runtime instance error=Runtime panicked: Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block
2023-06-22 21:58:48 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-06-22 21:58:48 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-06-22 21:58:48 ❗️ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block. Dropping.    
2023-06-22 21:58:48 Evicting failed runtime instance error=Runtime panicked: Sequencer address must be set for the block
2023-06-22 21:58:48 Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Runtime panicked: Sequencer address must be set for the block    
2023-06-22 21:58:52  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x169c…c26d), finalized #0 (0x169c…c26d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

So, we start with `true`, so the `on_finalize` hook does not fail at proposing block #1. In order to avoid the inherent panic, I added [a fix to the pallet](https://github.com/keep-starknet-strange/madara/blob/main/crates/pallets/starknet/src/lib.rs#L411), now we skip the inherent check for block 1, and start with block 2. So flow is block 1 `true` -> finalize to `false`, block 2 `false` -> inherent to `true` -> finalize to `false`.

Question: is this fix good? Why starting the hook and the inherent both at the start of the chain creates the panics? Thank you!

Comment: Why does `set_sequencer_address` panic instead of returning an error?

Comment: Hi Oliver, not 100% sure, but looking at inherent errors [implementations](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/75be6e2a6cc86cfa11390a05f113a00c270cdb24/primitives/inherents/src/lib.rs#L372), is it intended that the runtime panics when an inherent fails?

Comment: Yes I was not aware of that. Looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

Replacing

```
assert!(!SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::exists(), "Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block");
```

with

```
assert!(SeqAddrUpdate::<T>::get() == false, "Sequencer address can be updated only once in the block");
```

solved the panics when starting both hook and inherent at the start with `false`. Before, with the `false` that was put into storage, the inherent panicked because it did not expect that a value exists in storage explicitly, so it panicked and didn't set it to `true`, `on_finalize` hook panicked because `.take()` expected that the value exists and is set to `true`. The first time the inherent can go through is after the `on_finalize` takes the value in block 1, so it's indeed OK to do the storage check on block 2.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked locally just by removing everything related to `seq_addr_updated` from the genesis config and chainspec.rs.
Plus removing your fix to start from block 1 instead of genesis.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, this makes sense, I think it's the same idea, to let it check for non-existence but make sure it's not set at the start